# Some images not showing up, linking not working in react native

Tags: react-native

**EDIT**: The image issue has been resolved, but still not sure about Linking.

Okay so I'm having two weird questions. And apologies ahead of time for the code.

First thing's first, some images will simply not display even though they're valid. When running this in my IOS simulator, the very first image will not display. But some images always work.

The second thing, and let me know if this should be two separate questions, is linking to an external site. It doesn't appear to be able to do the Linking.open in IOS. So I wondered what is the easiest way, through linking or otherwise, of simply opening an external URL in both android and IOS?

Thanks a lot!

```
  openUrl(url) {
    Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
        if (supported) {
          Linking.open(url);
        } else {
          console.log('nope :: ' + url);
        }
    }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
      // browser.open(url);
  },


  renderImage(event, index) {
      if (this.state.showBox && this.state.boxIndex == index) {
        return (
          <View>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this._clickImage(event, index)}>
                <Image source={{ uri: event.image }} style={[styles.image, this.calculatedSize(), this.getImageStyles(event.featured), { height: 100 }]} />
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <View style={{ flexDirection:'row', padding: 15 }}>
                <Text style={styles.price}>{event.price}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.time}>{event.time}</Text>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this.openUrl(event.website)}>
                    <Text style={styles.btn}>Website</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>

                {renderif(event.venue)(
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this.openUrl(event.venue)}>
                        <Text style={styles.btn}>Venue</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                )}

          </View>
        )


      } else {
        return (
          <View>
              <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this._clickImage(event, index)}>
                  <Image source={{ uri: event.image }} style={[styles.image, this.calculatedSize(), this.getImageStyles(event.featured)]} />
              </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        )
      }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because some of your images are trying to load image from http connection.IOS apps require you to use https for images.

For example in this

```
{
      title: 'test',
      image: 'http://www.piedmontpark.org/images/bird_pine_warbler_330.jpg',
      featured: true,
      category: 'Music',
      price: '$8.00',
      time: '7:00 PM-11:00 PM',
      venue: '',
      website: 'http://google.com'
  }
```

Your 'image' is trying to load a jpg from http.

[Check this out on how to configure your info.plist to accept http](https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked, was a weird one to debug. Any thoughts on the linking issue?

Comment: It's actually a good practise to load your images using https, security-wise